# Vim - ex mode command - is there any way to move the cursor position?

Tags: vim, scripting, ex-mode

In a one line Vim ex command:

I am trying to do a command and then move to another location and execute the same command.

is there any way to move the cursor position (need both left/right and up/down)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The '|' is the command separator in Vim scripts.

```
:command the_first | second command
```

executes two commands.

There is also the :normal command which allows you to execute normal mode commands, like motion commands, from the Ex command line.  So maybe you can do something like

```
:/pat.*$/d | exec "normal 32G5w" | /pat.*$/d
```

There's probably an easier way to do what you're trying to do, however, if you can be more specific.

Comment: Normal does not allow to use another commands after it, so you will have to use `:execute`. And you do not have closing `/` in substitute.

Comment: @ZyX You don't need to close a substitute unless you're adding flags.

Comment: @Zenexer You do have to close the `:substitute` though, since there are more commands coming afterwards.

Comment: @glts Interesting.  vim is one thing that I can never quite seem to conquer.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not completely clear but I think you mean to use recording. I hope you know h,j,k,l movement commands. Try this:

```
    <goto command mode>
    qa
    i
    dddd
    <esc>
    j
    q
    @a
```

`qa` is the command to start recording in the buffer `a`. `q` is used to stop recording. You can use the buffer `a` by `@a`. Also try `10@a` to do the operation 10 times.